# Problems with matcher

Tags: java, matcher

I have to find words or regexps in the text and use `java.util.regexp.Matcher for this`

The method which must do it I have the following:

```
final ArrayList<String> regexps = config.getProperty(property);
for (String regexp: regexps){
     Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("." + regexp + ".", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
     Matcher mt = pt.matcher(plainText);            
         if (mt.find()){
            result = result + "DENIED. reason: " + property;
            reason = false;
            LOG.info("reason " + mt.group() + regexp);
            }
 }
```

but this code for some reason can't find the regexp `в[ыy][шs]лит[еe]` in the text

```
Вышлите пожалуйста новый счет на оплату на asda, пока согласовывали, уже
прошли его сроки. Лицензионный догово
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned if you have set locale?

Comment: how to do this? is this important, you think. As for me I guessed that  message can contain english or russian text or both.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong. You needn't worry for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

- you specify a dot before and after the match; as a result, it requires one character around each word; try and replace your dots with `\b` (or `"\\b"` as a Java string), which is the word anchor;
- you specify `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`. But [this flag only works for ASCII](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE). If you want matching on other characters, you MUST add [`Pattern.UNICODE_CASE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE) to your pattern compile flags.

That is:

```
Pattern.compile("whatever", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

As a final note, `[ee]` and `e` are equivalent, you probably meant something else here.

Comment: oh, I meant russian and english e. they can be replaced to circumvent security.

Comment: @NikitinMikhail security? What does security have to do with this?

Comment: If you are so interested, This app is used to separate spam e-mail messages from not spam messages. User creates rules himself and himself decide which words describes this message as spam for him. Spamer can replace russian е with english e to circumvent this spam filter, as they look identically and don't change the meaning of the message.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("." + regexp + ".", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

with:

```
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(".*" + regexp + ".*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```